# ElasticSearch - Reindex from Remote on a schedule, with daily deletions on the source index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index (we'll call it index01) on an ElasticSearch instance #1 (we'll call this ES1) on a Linux box in the US.  I have another ElasticSearch instance on a Linux box in the UK (we'll call it ES2).  What I need to do is duplicate index01 from ES1 to ES2, once-a-day.

At first thought it seemed it would be easy enough using the Reindex from Remote functionality but now I'm overwhelmed, and confused by the documentation.

So I first created an index on ES2 called index01, using the exact same settings and parameters as index01 on ES1.  Then, per the documentation, I'm supposed to make this call to build the index:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://otherhost:9200",
      "username": "user",
      "password": "pass"
    },
    "index": "source",
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "test": "data"
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dest"
  }
}
```

Turns out I don't need to put anything in the `query` clause as the `match` part since I just want to bring the entire index over.

1st question:  Each day, index01 on ES1 has many documents added to it *and* many documents **deleted** from it.  How do I keep the two indexes in sync and make sure index01 on ES2 matches ES1 exactly?

2nd question - is it possible to do this on a schedule using only Postman, or will I need to build an application in order to make this sync happen every 24 hours?

Answer (score 1):

Reindex just copies information from one index to another index. It doesn't track the changes.

So, the answer to first question is you can't using simple reindex. You should delete the index from ES2 and after reindex the index from ES1.

If it were no deletes in ES1, the index delete step was not necessary, due to `op_type:create` property. (Check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html )

Regarding second question, you can do this directly from Postman, using 2 calls :

- first call: delete index from ES2
- second call: reindex from ES1 to ES2

Comment: Thanks banuj.  To clarify question 2, is it possible to run these 2 calls **automatically** on a schedule (say once every 24 hours) in Postman, or do I have to build an application to do this?

Comment: Also, I wasn't clear on this in my original post, but deleting index from ES2 first isn't an option b/c the index on ES2 needs to be continued to be searchable by customers until the updated index is fully in place.

Comment: I see a paramater under the Reindex In Place documentation called `refresh_interval` which to me implies that I don't necessarily need to trigger a schedule, but rather the index on ES2 can refresh itself?  That's a step closer, but still doesn't address the fact that I need to track changes from ES1.

Comment: :) refresh_interval set to -1 means that no indexing happens. (So, the index is actually freezed).

Comment: Is there an option then to do reindexing with change tracking in any way?  The problem with deleting then re-indexing is the the index is unavailable to our clients from the time it gets deleted until the time the new, updated one is indexed